# How to check the user session in flutter and going through routes?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using below code in flutter to launch the app, it is working on routes,but i want if the user is already logged in then it should move to the `HomePage()` otherwise to the `LandingPage`, but as I implemented it did not worked. Please suggest, how could it be done?

I am using Firebase Authentication.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Social',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: buildThemeData(),
      onGenerateRoute: router.generateRoute,
      initialRoute: landingViewRoute,
      home: _handleAuth(),
    );
  }

  Widget _handleAuth() {
    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        return (!snapshot.hasData)
            ? HomePage()
            : LandingPage();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Go ahead and build the home page for unsigned user, blank. And rebuild the page with signed user or route to landing page after onAuthStateChanged callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StreamBuilder(
         stream: auth.onAuthChange,
         builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.active){
          User user =snapshot.data;

          if(user==null){
            return AuthOptions();
          }

          else{

                      return ClientDashBoard();

                }
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.pinkAccent),));
            });
          }
        }
        if(snapshot.hasError){
          return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error),);
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.pinkAccent),),);
```

this is what i used on my app for firebase auth.

use connectionStatus on authStateChange of FirebaseAuth because if data is null snapshot.hasData doesn't get called.